# android.view.InflateException when extending AppCompatSpinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-custom-view, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I have successfully created custom views in the past extending LinearLayout or android.support.v7.widget.CardView, however I can't seem to get it working when extending from android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner. I don't see why it is a problem for this specific class so I must be overlooking something.

I have the following class CustomSpinner

```
public class CustomSpinner extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner {

    public CustomSpinner(Context context)
    {
       this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
       super(context, attrs);
       init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
       super(context, attrs, defStyle);
       init(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
       LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
       inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_custom_spinner, this);
    }
}
```

And the R.layout.view_custom_spinner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/view_custom_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/minimum_clickable_area"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

And I use the custom component in another layout for 'MyFragment' like this (line #11 mentioned in the stacktrace):

```
<my.custom.namespace.CustomSpinner
    android:id="@+id/view_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

The strange thing is that when I extend the CustomSpinner class from LinearLayout everything is working fine and I don't get an InflateException.

I get the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.custom.namespace.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class my.custom.namespace.CustomSpinner
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3320)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7407)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #11: my.custom.namespace.CustomSpinner
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                                         at my.custom.namespace.MyFragment.onCreateView(MyFragment.java:183)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2261)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1750)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1819)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2590)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2377)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2332)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2239)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3231)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3181)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:192)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:572)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
                                                                         at my.custom.namespace.BaseActivity.onStart(BaseActivity.java:258)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1266)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6943)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3277)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7407) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class my.custom.namespace.CustomSpinner
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:843)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                         at my.custom.namespace.MyFragment.onCreateView(MyFragment.java:183) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2261) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1750) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1819) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2590) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2377) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2332) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2239) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3231) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3181) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:192) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:572) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177) 
                                                                         at my.custom.namespace.BaseActivity.onStart(BaseActivity.java:258) 
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1266) 
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6943) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3277) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7407) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1001) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:843) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                         at my.custom.namespace.MyFragment.onCreateView(MyFragment.java:183) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2261) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1750) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1819) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2590) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2377) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2332) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2239) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3231) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3181) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:192) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:572) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177) 
                                                                         at my.custom.namespace.BaseActivity.onStart(BaseActivity.java:258) 
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1266) 
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6943) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3277) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7407) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file l
```

Comment: `I have successfully created custom views in the past extending LinearLayout or android.support.v7.widget.CardView` Hmmm  That sounds strange. Can you post the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get why you are inflating the layout of the spinner. The spinner has its own layout by itself, you don't need to create the xml with a spinner inside. For linear layout it makes sense to inflate your own layout beacause it's a ViewGroup and inside your custom view class you can bind the linear layout's children, but for the spinner simply work on the spinner layout elements, using your custom view attributes to edit the layout. 
In summary, you can't add children to a spinner layout, so it doesn't make sense to inflate a custom xml for it. Simply remove 
`LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_custom_spinner, this);`
from your code and you'll have a perfectly working class extending the spinner.

Comment: I see now, I'll just have to add minHeight and gravity programmatically. I will need to revisit my solution for the custom CardView as well because I'm probably adding a CardView to another CardView.

Comment: Yeah, probably you should use the same approach with a CardView